# how to make 2 centered images responsive in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap on my site.  I have 2 images that are side by side and centered on my page.  When the site is shrunk they go on top of each other at the correct window size.  However, when I make the window small enough where the images should start shrinking, they don't shrink and it pushes content off the page.  I know it is those 2 images because I can remove them and the page shrinks further.
Here is my relevant html:

```
<div class="row">
        <a href="http://flash.clubschoicefundraising.com/CookieDoughAndMore-2014" class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/Otis_fund_logo.png")" alt="Otis Spunkmeyer" class="img-responsive center-block" /></a>
        <a href="http://flash.clubschoicefundraising.com/AuntieAnnes-2014/" class="col-md-10"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/Auntie-Annes.jpg")" alt="Auntie Annes" class="img-responsive center-block" /></a>
</div>
```

And here is the site where you can view it in action: http://clubschoicefundraising.com/

Those 2 images are at the very bottom of the page.  The Otis Spunkmeyer and Auntie Annes pictures.

**Added to clarify**: So basically when the browser is shrunk to tablet/phone size where those bottom images should be dynamically shrinking, they are not.

Comment: They seem to be stacking they way they should even at max-zoomed and are not pushing any content from what I can see. Can you clarify a little bit more regarding the issue you're encountering.

Comment: looks like they are shrinking to me

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I tried it in the other browsers and it appears to shrink correctly in Chrome, but not Firefox or IE.

Comment: I'm kind of getting sick of people down voting my questions and not making a comment on how my question can be improved.

Comment: You got one downvote on this question over 2 hours... And 3 of your 53 questions have a negative score... If you want to know why *this* question got a downvote, I'd have to guess that the person didn't want to visit an external site to debug your code. I think this is a fine question, and that's the only improvement I can see.

Comment: appreciate it @TimLewis

Comment: No problem. There are **always** going to be people who take one look at a question and downvote it, regardless of its quality. Just keep doing what you're doing; reputation is just a number anyway :P